# Tizku L'Shanim Rabot tovot v'umot?

Tags: blessing, words, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, rosh-hashanah-new-year, communities

I was wished this blessing today by a Spanish/Portuguese-descended friend.

What is the last word and, by extension, what does the entire phrase mean?

My friend did not know, but he said it was a standard Rosh HaShanah blessing among the Spanish/Portuguese, Turkish, Italian Sepharadim, and a few other communities.

Comment: Perhaps it was V'Naumot

Comment: Tizku leshanim rabot vetovot.

Comment: I found this. Hope it is helpful. http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/words/1303

Comment: @Gershon What does that mean? נעומות?

Comment: @DoubleAA: pleasant

Comment: @Gershon Like from the word Na'im נעים? Isn't the plural Ne'imot נעימות?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a corruption of "tovot v'neimot" -- may you (plural) merit to many good, pleasant years.

If you check with Rabbi Google, searching on תזכו לשנים רבות טובות, you'll see the concluding word is generally "ne'imot."

[This website](http://www.learnhebrewpod.com/explore/jewish-holidays/rosh-hashana/information) (of which I know nothing else) records a Sephardic practice where you say "may you merit to many years", and the other fellow replies -- "good and pleasant!"

Comment: Good find! תזכו לשנים רבות טובות ונעימות!

Answer (score 0):

It's Tizkey (Singular) or Tizku (Plurial) le Shanim Rabot ve Nehimot Tovot -  May you be granted many pleasant and good years.